# Restrict access to Django template

Tags: django

I need to restrict access to a template in Django. This is the scenario:

1. A guest user uses a form
2. If the form is validated and fine send the user to the `example.com/success/` url.
3. If the guest user tries to send that link `example.com/success` to a friend. The friend will see that page as a 404.

I have no clue how to achieve this. Any ideas?

Comment: What access *do* they need? to be logged in? to have a certain permission? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Your mistake is in thinking this has anything to do with templates. It's the view you need to restrict access to.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not thinking this has to do with templates. I know I need to define the logic in the view. And Sayse the access would be only view the template. Should I use sessions (cookies) or something like that to know that the current guest user can access the view?

Comment: One thing that I can understand out of this is that you are talking about user authentication, think about that and read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to a different URL (/success/), you could just show something different when the form was properly filled. For example, in your view:

```
def my_view(request, ...):
    form = ...
    show_success = False

    if ... post method ...:
        if form.is_valid():
             ... save etc. ...
             show_success = True

    return render(request, ..., {'show_success': show_success})
```

In your template:

```
{% if show_success %}
    Success message here
{% else %}
    Form here
{% endif %}
```